# Cookie is the same from two different browser machine clients

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies

I have two browsers from two different machines hitting a test page. The test page is retrieving a cookie. If one is not there, it creates a cookie.

```
public string GetUserCookieId()
{
    string cookieName = "CookieId3";

    HttpCookie userInfoCookies = Request.Cookies[cookieName];

    string cookieId = "";

    if (userInfoCookies != null)
        cookieId = userInfoCookies.Value;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieId))
    {
        cookieId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        cookie.Value = cookieId;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
        Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    }

    return cookieId;
}
```

Both browser machines are displaying the same cookie value on the page. This even once I have renamed the cookie to "CookieId3". Please tell me where i am going wrong.

As you can see, the method is not static. Thank you

Comment: Interesting. Looks ok to me at the moment; if you replace Guid.NewGuid().ToString() with Request.UserHostAddress(), do you get the cookie set to the same IP address displayed on the page?

Comment: Perhaps you set the page to be cached?

Comment: I meant output caching or some other server cache (e.g. load balancer).  Check there are no `[OutputCache]` attributes anywhere.

Comment: Current scenario is this. Machine#1 gets new cookie. Machine#2 (which does not have a cookie, gets the same value as set by Machine#1). Stepping through the code. Machine#2 never generates a new cookie value. Machine#2 does not have a cookie but some how retrieves the same value as Machine#1. I am now up to Cookie16. How can this be?

Comment: Machine#2 never gets an entry of say Cookie16 in its cookie list via Request["HTTP_COOKIES"], however, it will grab the value that Machine #1 had set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be the difference between Request and HttpContext.Current.Request when the code is accessed from a ClassLibrary.

Is anyone is able to shed some light on this?!

The following works.

```
public string GetUserCookieId()
{
    string cookieName = "CookieId18";

    HttpCookie userInfoCookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

    string cookieId = "";

    if (userInfoCookies != null)
        cookieId = userInfoCookies.Value;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieId))
    {
        cookieId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        cookie.Value = cookieId;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(cookie);
    }

    return cookieId;
}
```

Comment: Oooh. Check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/httpcontext-request - in a page, Request is resolving to the 'Request' member of HttpApplication (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx ).  In the context of a new class you're writing, you won't have that resolution. What you've got now will work, or pass the relevant HttpContext to GetUserCookieId() to generalize (it will make unit tests easier).